# How do I run two rails apps behind the same domain and have nginx route requests based on cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I need to run 2 identical Rails apps (different only in the underlying database) behind the same domain (e.g. mydomain.com) and have Nginx route requests to RailsApp1 or RailsApp2 depending on the existence of a cookie in the request.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question has already bene asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936329/nginx-redirect-if-cookie-present

Comment: can you explain more the requirements please? why rely on cookies?

Comment: Because which database is used depends on who is logged in. After a user logs in, a cookie is set that says which database should be used.

Comment: OK now I'm thinking of using Rack::Proxy for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about write a rails app as the proxy?