# Routing traffic between two servers based on a cookie

Tags: django, cookies, nginx, url-routing

We are presently rewriting an in-production Django site. We would like to deploy the new site in parallel with the old site, and slowly divert traffic from old to new using the following scheme:

- New accounts go to the new site
- Existing accounts go to the old site
- Existing accounts may be offered the opportunity to opt in to the new site
- Accounts diverted to the new site may opt out and be returned to the old site

It's clear to me that a cookie is involved, and that Nginx is capable of rewriting requests based on a cookie:

- [Nginx redirect if cookie present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936329/nginx-redirect-if-cookie-present)
- [How do I run two rails apps behind the same domain and have nginx route requests based on cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718264/how-do-i-run-two-rails-apps-behind-the-same-domain-and-have-nginx-route-requests)

How the cookie gets set remains a bit of a mystery to me. It seems like a chicken-and-egg problem. Has anyone successfully run a scheme like this? How did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most suitable solution for you problem would be:

1. Nginx at every request should check for some specific cookie, `route`
2. If it's presented and equals `old`, request goes to a `old` site
3. Otherwise request goes to the `new`  site.
4. Every site (new and old) should check request for that  cookie (`route`)
5. If cookie isn't presented (or wrong), your app should set it to the right value, and if request is for that site, just proceed it.
6. If not, it should send `redirect`, and we begin again with step `1`

Comment: That seems clear enough. I suppose that it's inevitable that an existing customer will see the new site if they come with a fresh session, but it's not the end of the world. I could start setting the "old" cookie now, so that when we launch the new site, the majority of regulars won't know the difference.