# web proxy to URL in cookie value

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I want to config reverse proxy server to be able to proxy client for a new server which created specifically for him.

So let say, client A logged in  http://server.com , and has a cookie proxy_url=http://ec2-2323A.server.com  so this solution is proxy him to this server, while he see only http://server.com in the main page.

I tried to do it with nginx reading this [Nginx redirect if cookie present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936329/nginx-redirect-if-cookie-present)
but get some silly errors,
and my custom configuration seems not working

```
  location / {
  set $upstream 127.0.0.1:8080/;
      if ($http_cookie ~* "proxy_url=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $upstream $1;
      }
      proxy_pass $upstream;
...
```

Any simple solution or other servers?

Comment: 1. You need a `resolver` at least. 2. There is `$cookie_...` variables. 3. You have to construct whole url in `proxy_pass` if you use variables.

Comment: Can you perhaps show the errors?