# Nginx Redirect to Cookie-Consent Page if Consent Cookie not Set

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nextcloud

This question refers to almost the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936329/nginx-redirect-if-cookie-present). As nginx only allows `if` and within the `if` clause only a `return`, `rewrite` and `proxy_pass`, etc. but `try_files`, and `else` or `NOT` may not be used.

So the issue: I want to model the following (in pseudo nginx configuration)

```
location / {
  if (NOT  isset(cookie("cookie-consent")) ) {
    return 302 "https://example.com/cookieconsent";
  }
  else {
    # I am running the site on a backend server
    proxy_pass https://example.com:8443;
  }
}

# The HTML here has a button to agree to the use of said cookies
location /cookieconsent {
  root /path/to/www-root;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html;
}

location /setconsent {
  add_header Set-Cookie 'consent=true;Domain=$host;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000;SameSite=strict;HTTPOnly;Secure';
  return 302 https://$host;
}
```

The background of this is that I am using Nextcloud and since Nextcloud uses functional cookies only, it is sufficient that users are informed of the use of cookies through a popup, however Nextcloud has no GDPR Cookie Consent plugin, nor am I intrigued to develop one. So the easiest alternative is to check if a user had been informed about the use of cookies and display the cookie consent page at first otherwise before the actual site is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As powerful as nginx is, there's of course a working solution to the above problem. Actually, the reason I added the question was to publish this answer since I believe that it might help others, and of course me too in case I forget how I achieved it as time passes and google for a quick solution. Without further ado, here's my solution in the nginx configuration file:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header HOST example.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  
  if( $http_cookie ~* "consent" ) {
    proxy_pass https://example.com:8443;
  }
  
  # Setting `return 302` directly here doesn't work well
  # the first argument is just a filler as entering '@noconsent' only is disallowed
  try_files $uri/$arg_key @noconsent;
}

location @noconsent {
  return 302 "https://example.com/cookieconsent";
}

location /cookieconsent {
  root /path/to/www-root;
  expires max;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html;
}

location /setconsent {
  add_header Set-Cookie 'consent=true;Domain=$host;Path=/;Max-Age=7776000;SameSite=strict;HTTPOnly;Secure';
  return 302 https://$host;
}
```

What this configuration does is to 302 redirect to 'https://example.com/cookieconsent' if cookie not set. In there, it searches for '/cookieconsent/index.html' and 'cookieconsent.html'. Either of those files should be present and readable by the server. It should also include a button or link that triggers '/setconsent'. Thenafter, the `consent` cookie is set such that the condition is `true` and `proxy_pass` is triggered (Nextcloud is loaded in this case).

The nice feature of this is that one can do this purely in HTML without setting any cookies until the explicit consent was given by the visitor as required by GDPR laws. On the other hand, a visitor cannot visit the actual website without agreeing to the use of cookies first.